# Cassandra Table schema for querying table on multiple column

Tags: java, linux, database, database-design, cassandra

In Cassandra , I'am facing a big issue in creating a table schema. Please provide best suggestions.
Currently using Cassandra version 3.9

My table :-

```
CREATE TABLE call (
    date text,
    dt timestamp,
    calledno text,
    callerno text,
    calltype text,
    channelno int,
    comment text,
    dpc text,
    opc text,
    systemno int,
    trackno int,
    traffictype text,
    id uuid,
    PRIMARY KEY (systemno,trackno,date,id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (trackno ASC,date ASC)
```

Now my Searches will be based on following types :-

1. Only DT (on Single date and sometimes on range based )
2. DT , SystemNo , TrackNo
3. DT , OPC , DPC ( For all SystemNo and TrackNo)
4. DT , Comment
5. DT , CallerNo
6. DT , CalledNo
7. DT , Channel No
8. DT , CallerNo , CalledNo

Write load on this table is very high somewhere around let say 4k-5k insert record per second.

Need to know how many minimum tables or materialised views can be created to achieve these searches with max read speed.

Comment: Do not hesitate to create tables while modeling cassandra. Design table according to your query.

Comment: Hi Gunwant, Thank you for the response but I'am little worried about maintaining so many tables so want to have minimum configuration possible. Hence , needed suggestions on the same.

Comment: You need to give more information, like for 2) DT , SystemNo , TrackNo -- Do you want unique Cell numbers or not?

Comment: Ok. So, I'll give an example like i have 3 system no and 2 tracks so for any combination of system and track i want all the data from this table based on that particular date. So basically yes each row item will be unique always.